# Wget out of memory error kills process

Tags: wget, out-of-memory

I wanted to backup all my .vcf files from my carddav server (ownCloud). The script is very simple and is the following:

```
$ wget -Avcf -r -np -l0 --no-check-certificate -e robots=off --user=user \
    --password='password' https://cloud.domain.com/foo/carddav
```

The total number of .vcf files is about 400, after downloading about 70 of them, wget returns this error:

[image: ss of error]

*original URL: http://oi40.tinypic.com/2ch9itt.jpg*

Which kills the process because the system is "out of memory". The system is a Debian Wheezy virtual machine, hosted on Windows 7. I tried to raise the RAM to 1024MB instead of the actual 128MB, but the problem still exists.

Any suggestions on how to work around this or alternative ways to accomplish this?

Comment: [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) might be an alternative to wget in your case. It is available in Debian.

Comment: wget was consuming about 530MB of memory at the time it was killed, so that's very abnormal. Could you try with `curl`?

Comment: What is this -f switch?  wget doesn't seem to have such an option.

Comment: @jofel: thank you for the suggestion, I will use it as a last option if I can't do it with wget.

Comment: @psusi: there is no -f switch in my command, probably you saw the -A switch followed by the .vcf extension, without the dot. It is "-Avcf", where vcf is the argument of the switch -A.

Comment: Ahh, strange that that works... there should be a space between the switch and its argument.

Comment: @psusi: I know! I wrote it like that and did not notice the mistake because it works anyway.

Comment: Recursive download stores all the URLs in memory. «Of course, recursive download may cause problems on your machine. If left to run unchecked, it can easily fill up the disk. If downloading from local network, it can also take bandwidth on the system, as well as consume memory and CPU.» https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Download.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `wget` loops causes *memory overflow*.
The natural first suggestion is to increase again memory of your cloud instance from 1Gb to 2Gb. This solved a similar issue recently.

If this is not possible or doesn't solve the problem the second solution is to run `wget` within 2 steps:

1. Retrieve files list. As I see in your screenshot the files are in the directory `cloud.some_domain.com/remote.php/carddav/addressbooks/your_name/`.
   So, run `wget` to get the directory index:
   `wget https://cloud.some_domain.com/remote.php/carddav/addressbooks/your_name/`
   This will give you an `index.html` file.
2. Now you can parse it to retrieve the filenames to download:

   ```
   grep ".vcf" index.html | awk -F"href=" '{print $2}' | awk -F\" '{print $2}' > ALL_VCF_FILES.lst
   for elt in `cat ALL_VCF_FILES.lst`
   do
   wget https://cloud.some_domain.com/remote.php/carddav/addressbooks/your_name/$elt
   done
   rm ALL_VCF_FILES.lst index.html
   ```

Comment: thank you very much that's the best solution ti my problem! I'll let you know asap if it works.

Comment: You welcome ! I edited the code parts to match best your case (HTTPS)

Comment: I have to thank @Slyx! Your code was almost perfect.
The only problem was that the ALL_VCF_FILES.lst list was a list like /remote.php/carddav/addressbooks/user/contacts/xxxxxxxxx.vcf this means that the link is missing the "http://cloud.domain.com".
Using sed I made a simple find and replace like this:
sed 's/\/remote.php\/carddav\/addressbooks\/user\/contacts\//https:\/\/www.cloud.domain.com\/remote.php\/carddav\/addressbooks\/user\/contacts\//g' ALL_VCF_FILES.lst > all_vcf_files.lst
Maybe you can incorporate this in your answer to make the code complete.
It works like a charm!

Comment: wget --no-check-certificate -e robots=off --user=user --password='pswd' https://blabla

grep ".vcf" index.html | awk -F"href=" '{print $2}' | awk -F\" '{print $2}' > ALL_VCF_FILES.lst
sed 's/\/remote.php\/carddav\/addressbooks\/user\/contacts\//https:\/\/cloud.domain.com\/remote.php\/carddav\/addressbooks\/user\/contacts\//g' ALL_VCF_FILES.lst > all_vcf_files.lst
for elt in `cat all_vcf_files.lst`
do
wget -nc --no-check-certificate -e robots=off --user=user --password='pswd' $elt
done
rm ALL_VCF_FILES.lst index.html all_vcf_files.lst
mv *.vcf /home/scripts/owncloud_backup/vcf/

Comment: @user3161330 instead of adding a `sed` line we can just add the missing part of the URL before the `$elt` variable. See my edit. 2nd : you have the pathchain in your index.html because you requested this specific file in your `wget` commad.

Comment: I suggest to put the -nc switch in the last wget command because all the links in the ALL_VCF_FILES.lst are double, otherwise you would download all the .vcf two times.

Comment: Wow, great solution! Even I have learned something new: that I can use `-F` option in `awk` with a whole expression and not just a single character. BTW the reason why I assumed I couldn't do that is the following: `cut` in comparison will indeed only allow you exactly one character as _delimiter_ (which is a similar effect that `-F` has in `awk`)